# What is the correct way to convert a YCBCR_420_888 image to RAW10 format?

Tags: c++, image, raw, ycbcr

I'm having trouble converting the image correctly. Is that even possible? There is no answer to this question on the Internet. The difference between image formats is catastrophically large. If RAW10 is to be taken from the camera sensor, then maybe conversion is not possible?
How do I correctly calculate the size of a RAW10 image?

I calculate it this way:

```
    width * height
```

Not working:

```
    width * height * 5 / 2
```

Not working:

```
    width * height * sizeof(uint16_t)
```

Here's my non-working function.

```
    void ConvertYCbCr420888ToRaw10(const android_ycbcr & srcYCbCr,
      std::vector < uint8_t > & dst_raw, int width,
      int height) {
      uint8_t * yPlane = static_cast < uint8_t * > (srcYCbCr.y);
      uint8_t * cbPlane = static_cast < uint8_t * > (srcYCbCr.cb);
      uint8_t * crPlane = static_cast < uint8_t * > (srcYCbCr.cr);
      for (int y = 0; y < height; ++y) {
        for (int x = 0; x < width; ++x) {
          dst_raw[y * width + x] = yPlane[y * width + x];
        }
      }

      for (int y = 0; y < height / 2; ++y) {
        for (int x = 0; x < width / 2; ++x) {
          uint8_t cb = cbPlane[y * width / 2 + x];
          uint8_t cr = crPlane[y * width / 2 + x];

          uint16_t cb10 = (cb << 2) | ((cb >> 6) & 0x03);
          uint16_t cr10 = (cr << 2) | ((cr >> 6) & 0x03);

          dst_raw[height * width + y * width / 2 + x] = (cb10 >> 8) & 0xFF;
          dst_raw[height * width + y * width / 2 + x + 1] = cb10 & 0xFF;
          dst_raw[height * width + y * width / 2 + width / 2 + x] = (cr10 >> 8) & 0xFF;
          dst_raw[height * width + y * width / 2 + width / 2 + x + 1] = cr10 & 0xFF;
        }
      }
    }
```

For example, the image canvas size is 4000x3000. Then this function fills 70% of the image with lilac color. The other 30% is empty. The image is distorted with stripes on the diagonal.

Comment: The *correct* way to perform image manipulation is usually to use a library.  See [softwarerecs.se].

Comment: The title says you want to convert YCbCr to RAW10. Then, in the question you mention reading RAW10 from the sensor... which isn't converting **into** RAW10 but **from** RAW10? Also, you provide no images and no links to the specifications or cameras you are using?

Comment: Reminder:  `width / 2` is **integer division** and will be truncated.

Comment: I recommend helping the compiler and assigning common values to constant temporary values.  For example: `const int half_width_y = y * width / 2;`.  Some compilers may perform this at higher level optimizations.  IMHO, compilers can always use some help.  Look for patterns in your code. :-)  Another benefit is that you can examine these values, with a debugger, before they are applied.

Comment: Verify that your vector indices are within range:  replace `[]` with `.at()`.  The `at()` applies range checking.

Comment: What part of your program is *Not Working*?  Please use a debugger and find out which statement(s) are not working correctly.  Edit your post to identify the statement location, the expected values of the variables in question and their actual values.